# Dynamic/static analysis of method resolution order in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-mro

Is there a way that I can pragmatically determine, either at runtime, or via static analysis, the [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) for a given python class?

Imagine I have a set of classes

```
class A():
    ...

class B(A):
    ...

class C(A):
    ...

class D(B, C):
    def print_mro(self):
         print("D, B, C, A")
```

I want to find out the C3 linearization for them is without having to root through the source code and try to determine the order by hand. I'm working on a django app where the views have lots of mixins that have been up to now rather haphazardly ordered. I need to make sure that they are in the right order though, and for security reasons I don't want to 
 check my work by hand and risk a data leak. I also don't want to go through by hand and add a print statement to every mixin's dispatch method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
class A():
    pass

class B(A):
   pass

class C(A):
    pass

class D(B, C):
    def print_mro(self):
         print(self.__class__.__mro__)

d = D()
d.print_mro()
```

?

Answer (score -1):

you can also do-

```
d = D()
print(help(d))
```